# How can I date my entries into a latex document? (Not just one date, but several dates)

Tags: formatting, datetime

I know the \date command inserts a date in the title, but as I keep working on this document of mine I want to be able to keep a record of what I wrote on each day. I've been simply writing the date now every time I write every day, but I was wondering if there was a command I could use to place the date in a less obtrusive part that's not the body of my document.

Comment: You could use a `%` symbol in your source prior to the date.  It would not appear in your typeset document, but would be part of your source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a version control system (VCS) to keep track of changes on your document. VCS are not only for programming source code, it works great on LaTeX document also.  I have used VCS for my own documents.

There are currently a few that you could choose from:

- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
- [GIT](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)

There maybe more, but those are the ones I have used.

Comment: See also http://ctan.org/pkg/vc.